# Saving scatter graph as image in C#

Tags: c#, image, graph, bitmap, scatter

I'm plotting some scatter graphs from **SQL data** in a **c# program**. I would like automatically **save these graphs** as they populate. I have the following code which saves the Jpeg files, but when I open them, they are **empty**. I'm plotting multiple graphs at once.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public partial class XYplotForm : Form
    {
        public XYplotForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public void Plot(Double[] freq, Double[] amp, Double[] bw, string name)
        {
            scatterGraph1.PlotXY(freq, amp);
            tbName.Text = name;

            Bitmap image = new Bitmap(scatterGraph1.Width, scatterGraph1.Height);
            Rectangle target_bounds = default(Rectangle);
            target_bounds.Width = scatterGraph1.Width;
            target_bounds.Height = scatterGraph1.Height;
            target_bounds.X = 0;
            target_bounds.Y = 0;
            scatterGraph1.DrawToBitmap(image, target_bounds);
            string filename = "C:\\Graph\\" + name + ".Jpeg";
            image.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);



            }


        }


    }
```

Comment: I solved my question

Answer (score 0):

```
xyForm = new XYplotForm();
        xyForm.Plot(freqLC40, ampMaxLC40, "LC-40 Max Amplitude");
        xyForm.Show();

        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(xyForm.Width, xyForm.Height);
        System.Drawing.Rectangle target_bounds = default(System.Drawing.Rectangle);
        target_bounds.Width = xyForm.Width;
        target_bounds.Height = xyForm.Height;
        target_bounds.X = 0;
        target_bounds.Y = 0;
        xyForm.DrawToBitmap(image, target_bounds);
        string filename =  "C:\\Graph\\LC40_Max Amplitude.Png";
        image.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```